# How can i optimize this query MYSQL

Tags: mysql, performance

Hello everyone i have this query but I don't know how to optimize this query. I will be thankful if someone can guide me here thanks in advance.

```
SELECT
    Jobs.id AS `Jobs__id`,
    Jobs.name AS `Jobs__name`,
    Jobs.media_id AS `Jobs__media_id`,
    Jobs.job_category_id AS `Jobs__job_category_id`,
    Jobs.job_type_id AS `Jobs__job_type_id`,
    Jobs.description AS `Jobs__description`,
    Jobs.detail AS `Jobs__detail`,
    Jobs.business_skill AS `Jobs__business_skill`,
    Jobs.knowledge AS `Jobs__knowledge`,
    Jobs.location AS `Jobs__location`,
    Jobs.activity AS `Jobs__activity`,
    Jobs.academic_degree_doctor AS `Jobs__academic_degree_doctor`,
    Jobs.academic_degree_master AS `Jobs__academic_degree_master`,
    Jobs.academic_degree_professional AS `Jobs__academic_degree_professional`,
    Jobs.academic_degree_bachelor AS `Jobs__academic_degree_bachelor`,
    Jobs.salary_statistic_group AS `Jobs__salary_statistic_group`,
    Jobs.salary_range_first_year AS `Jobs__salary_range_first_year`,
    Jobs.salary_range_average AS `Jobs__salary_range_average`,
    Jobs.salary_range_remarks AS `Jobs__salary_range_remarks`,
    Jobs.restriction AS `Jobs__restriction`,
    Jobs.estimated_total_workers AS `Jobs__estimated_total_workers`,
    Jobs.remarks AS `Jobs__remarks`,
    Jobs.url AS `Jobs__url`,
    Jobs.seo_description AS `Jobs__seo_description`,
    Jobs.seo_keywords AS `Jobs__seo_keywords`,
    Jobs.sort_order AS `Jobs__sort_order`,
    Jobs.publish_status AS `Jobs__publish_status`,
    Jobs.version AS `Jobs__version`,
    Jobs.created_by AS `Jobs__created_by`,
    Jobs.created AS `Jobs__created`,
    Jobs.modified AS `Jobs__modified`,
    Jobs.deleted AS `Jobs__deleted`,
    JobCategories.id AS `JobCategories__id`,
    JobCategories.name AS `JobCategories__name`,
    JobCategories.sort_order AS `JobCategories__sort_order`,
    JobCategories.created_by AS `JobCategories__created_by`,
    JobCategories.created AS `JobCategories__created`,
    JobCategories.modified AS `JobCategories__modified`,
    JobCategories.deleted AS `JobCategories__deleted`,
    JobTypes.id AS `JobTypes__id`,
    JobTypes.name AS `JobTypes__name`,
    JobTypes.job_category_id AS `JobTypes__job_category_id`,
    JobTypes.sort_order AS `JobTypes__sort_order`,
    JobTypes.created_by AS `JobTypes__created_by`,
    JobTypes.created AS `JobTypes__created`,
    JobTypes.modified AS `JobTypes__modified`,
    JobTypes.deleted AS `JobTypes__deleted`
FROM
    jobs Jobs
    LEFT JOIN jobs_personalities JobsPersonalities ON Jobs.id = (JobsPersonalities.job_id)
    LEFT JOIN personalities Personalities ON (Personalities.id = (JobsPersonalities.personality_id)
            AND(Personalities.deleted) IS NULL)
    LEFT JOIN jobs_practical_skills JobsPracticalSkills ON Jobs.id = (JobsPracticalSkills.job_id)
    LEFT JOIN practical_skills PracticalSkills ON (PracticalSkills.id = (JobsPracticalSkills.practical_skill_id)
            AND(PracticalSkills.deleted) IS NULL)
    LEFT JOIN jobs_basic_abilities JobsBasicAbilities ON Jobs.id = (JobsBasicAbilities.job_id)
    LEFT JOIN basic_abilities BasicAbilities ON (BasicAbilities.id = (JobsBasicAbilities.basic_ability_id)
            AND(BasicAbilities.deleted) IS NULL)
    LEFT JOIN jobs_tools JobsTools ON Jobs.id = (JobsTools.job_id)
    LEFT JOIN affiliates Tools ON (Tools.type = 1
            AND Tools.id = (JobsTools.affiliate_id)
            AND(Tools.deleted) IS NULL)
    LEFT JOIN jobs_career_paths JobsCareerPaths Page 3 / 4 ON Jobs.id = (JobsCareerPaths.job_id)
    LEFT JOIN affiliates CareerPaths ON (CareerPaths.type = 3
            AND CareerPaths.id = (JobsCareerPaths.affiliate_id)
            AND(CareerPaths.deleted) IS NULL)
    LEFT JOIN jobs_rec_qualifications JobsRecQualifications ON Jobs.id = (JobsRecQualifications.job_id)
    LEFT JOIN affiliates RecQualifications ON (RecQualifications.type = 2
            AND RecQualifications.id = (JobsRecQualifications.affiliate_id)
            AND(RecQualifications.deleted) IS NULL)
    LEFT JOIN jobs_req_qualifications JobsReqQualifications ON Jobs.id = (JobsReqQualifications.job_id)
    LEFT JOIN affiliates ReqQualifications ON (ReqQualifications.type = 2
            AND ReqQualifications.id = (JobsReqQualifications.affiliate_id)
            AND(ReqQualifications.deleted) IS NULL)
        INNER JOIN job_categories JobCategories ON (JobCategories.id = (Jobs.job_category_id)
                AND(JobCategories.deleted) IS NULL)
            INNER JOIN job_types JobTypes ON (JobTypes.id = (Jobs.job_type_id)
                    AND(JobTypes.deleted) IS NULL)
        WHERE ((JobCategories.name LIKE '%キャビンアテンダント%'
                OR JobTypes.name LIKE '%キャビンアテンダント%'
                OR Jobs.name LIKE '%キャビンアテンダント%'
                OR Jobs.description LIKE '%キャビンアテンダント%'
                OR Jobs.detail LIKE '%キャビンアテンダント%'
                OR Jobs.business_skill LIKE '%キャビンアテンダント%'
                OR Jobs.knowledge LIKE '%キャビンアテンダント%'
                OR Jobs.location LIKE '%キャビンアテンダント%'
                OR Jobs.activity LIKE '%キャビンアテンダント%'
                OR Jobs.salary_statistic_group LIKE '%キャビンアテンダント%'
                OR Jobs.salary_range_remarks LIKE '%キャビンアテンダント%'
                OR Jobs.restriction LIKE '%キャビンアテンダント%'
                OR Jobs.remarks LIKE '%キャビンアテンダント%'
                OR Personalities.name LIKE '%キャビンアテンダント%'
                OR PracticalSkills.name LIKE '%キャビンアテンダント%'
                OR BasicAbilities.name LIKE '%キャビンアテンダント%'
                OR Tools.name LIKE '%キャビンアテンダント%'
                OR CareerPaths.name LIKE '%キャビンアテンダント%'
                OR RecQualifications.name LIKE '%キャビンアテンダント%'
                OR ReqQualifications.name LIKE '%キャビンアテンダント%')
            AND publish_status = 1
            AND(Jobs.deleted) IS NULL)
    GROUP BY
        Jobs.id
    ORDER BY
        Jobs.sort_order DESC,
        Jobs.id DESC
    LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0
```

I know it's a long query but I have to optimize this no other options so need pro's guide thank you

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post DDL, sample data and expected data, along with the EXPLAIN. Without those, we can't help.

Comment: Have you set indexes in MySQL on all columns you have in the WHERE ?

Comment: i did thought of adding indexes but i think so maybe something more can be done to optimize the query

Comment: jea dont write such an monster^^
you won't want to hear this, but optimization starts with the structure and the whole program, i guess you have to adjust your structure in general to get a really optimized program

Comment: how many rows in your tables? The wildcards in your where clause will be slow for even moderate numbers of rows. Have you considered full-text indices?

Comment: Have you tryed to change the table engine ? Like if you are in innodb and don't need the features of innodb, try MyISAM or even Memory if you have enought RAM on your server. It's generaly huge boost in performances for me with MyISAM

Comment: I would start with something far simpler. The optimisation techniques we can show you for that would be applicable to your larger query.

Comment: @BackTrack57 - Don't backtrack to MyISAM.  The performance is likely to be worse.  Furthermore, MyISAM is going away.

Answer (score 0):

**Inefficient pattern**

```
                 OR  Jobs.restriction   LIKE '%キャビンアテンダント%'
                 OR  Jobs.remarks       LIKE '%キャビンアテンダント%'
                 OR  Personalities.name LIKE '%キャビンアテンダント%'
```

This is a common, but very inefficient, pattern.

- `OR` prevents use of indexes
- Leading wildcard in `LIKE` prevents use of an index
- `WHERE` clause touching multiple table hurts.

**Possible workaround**

I do see pattern that can possibly be turned into an optimization.  You seem to be checking a user-provided string against lots of columns.  If, instead of using `LIKE`, you could use `FULLTEXT`, then there is a much faster solution.  (Sorry, I don't know if Japanese can be used with `FULLTEXT`; you would possibly need MySQL 8.0, which has a lot of UTF-8 improvements.)

Here's the technique:

1. Collect the data from all those search columns (restriction, remarks, name, etc) into a single column, perhaps into a new table.
2. Apply `FULLTEXT` to that column.
3. Search only in that column; get the matching id to then `JOIN` to all the other tables.

**Fallback**

Even if `FULLTEXT` does not work well with Asian languages, a single string to apply `LIKE` to would help.

**Syntax error?**

```
 LEFT JOIN jobs_career_paths JobsCareerPaths Page 3 / 4 ON Jobs.id = (JobsCareerPaths.job_id)
```

looks like a syntax error.

**Composite index needed**

```
    LEFT JOIN  affiliates CareerPaths
          ON (CareerPaths.type = 3
         AND  CareerPaths.id = (JobsCareerPaths.affiliate_id)
         AND (CareerPaths.deleted) IS NULL
```

CareerPaths needs this composite index:

```
INDEX(type, id, deleted)
```

with the columns in any order.  3 separate indexes is *not* as good.  (Also check the other `JOINs`.)